# Unwanted characters in cached pages - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, character

I'm exploring the Rails caching in order to speedup the page loading of a website that is becoming very big passing the time. 
Said this i'am done the simple steps to enable caching on my pages and it works very well.
Using caches_page :page_name

I have only one issue - I find a lot of unwanted characters in my page, it is regarding letters like "à" or " ' ", " ° ".
E.g. : instead of "'" i got "â€™"

this is related both for text inside the database and static text in the page.

What should be the cause of this wrong font rendering?

My fonts are included in the fonts directory and work very well in the non cached pages - they are google fonts (Roboto and RobotoCondensed).

I'm using heroku for production and I don't know if I have to change some production environment configuration to manage this.

I got no errors in console and no other messages.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

there was a missing line in my  of the html layout file:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

this set the correct character encode on all the pages